# What's the reason for my cat going missing?

Tags: cats, psychology

I have a 3 year old male cat who has been neutered. He's name is Meow Meow and I had since he was about 3 or 4 weeks old. We've been very close and bonded really well. I have never been away from him for longer than the usual 8 hour work day.. maybe a night or two as well when I would sleep over somewhere.

The problem is that I left on the 6th December to go to Port Elizabeth for my sister's wedding. It's a 10 hour drive from where I live and I returned on the 14th December (8 days). Upon returning I found that Meow has just dissapeared. My other 3 cats are still here though. I had a family friend who came over each morning to let the cats out the house and feed them. She would return late afternoon to feed them again and let them back into the house.

She told me Meow was there on Sunday morning but when I got back home Sunday afternoon he was gone. He would never be gone for more than a few hours but it's been a whole 5 days now.

I'm starting to think that he left because he thought I wasn't coming back. Is this possible? Do cats behave and think in such terms?

Comment: It isn't impossible that he didn't like the new situation but could also be that he ran into something he couldn't handle while outside. There's no telling.

Comment: Not knowing is one of the hardest parts. I've been searching for him all over.

Comment: Have you contacted your local SPCA or other animal shelters?

Comment: Yes, I have been to my local SPCA but no luck. However, the chances of him approaching or getting caught by another human are slim to none because he's petrified of strangers.